# Identity for bracket operator in tangent space at identity

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $X,Y\in T_eG$. Show that

$$[X,Y]=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right\vert_{s=0}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{t=0}\exp(sX)\exp(tY)\exp(-sX)\exp(-tY).$$

No matter how I approach this I end up with the same wrong result.

By definition $$[X,Y]=\operatorname{ad}(X)Y=(T_e(\operatorname{Ad})X)Y$$

which in turn is

$$(T_e(\operatorname{Ad})X)Y=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right\vert_{s=0}\operatorname{Ad}(\exp(sX))Y=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right\vert_{s=0}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{t=0}\exp(\operatorname{Ad}(\exp(sX)tY))$$

and by a hint given on the sheet that's equal to $$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right\vert_{s=0}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{t=0}\exp(sX)\exp(tY)\exp(-sX)$$

What's my mistake?

Edit: The exact text of the question is:

Let now $G$ be a Lie group. The commutator of two elements $x,y\in G$ is the element $c(x,y):=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$. Show that for all $X,Y\in T_eG$ we have $$[X,Y]=\left.\frac\partial{\partial s}\right\vert_{s=0}\left.\frac\partial{\partial t}\right\vert_{t=0}c(\exp sX,\exp tY).$$ Hint: use relations like $x\exp Yx^{-1}=\exp(\operatorname{Ad}(x)Y)$.

Comment: The formula in the first line is right ?

Comment: In a text you added, more exactly formula, can you clarify s, t ? $c(\exp\ sX, \exp\ sY)$ ?

Comment: If we follow the posting, $[X,Y]=0$

Comment: Actually $(T_e(\operatorname{Ad})X)Y= (\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right\vert_{s=0}\operatorname{Ad}(\exp(sX))) Y$. It's missing the differential of the evaluation on $Y$.

Comment: @user188201 May do you have a reference ?

Comment: I did not see the problem. So I mean, is there a textbook or some note.

Comment: Yes. It's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Here $\exp (X)$ is integral curve for $X$ at identity.

(2) If $F: M\times N\rightarrow L$ is smooth, then $$ \frac{d}{dt}
F(c(t),d(t))= DF (c',d')=DF (c',0)+DF(0,d') $$
(cf. Lemma 5.3 in your lecture note or the proof of Lemma 5.2. That is $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\exp (tX)\exp (tY) =X+Y$

(3) $$\frac{d}{ds}\frac{d}{dt}
 \exp (sX)\exp(tY)\exp(-sX)\exp(-tY) 
= \frac{d}{ds}\frac{d}{dt}
  \exp \bigg(Ad_{\exp ( sX) } (tY)  \bigg)  \exp (-tY )  = \frac{d}{ds} [ 
 Ad_{\exp (sX) }Y-Y] =[X,Y]
$$